# passing params to constructor in partial classes and super, javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, super, sudoku

## Hay..

#### Current Situation

I have a function to render 9 Squares in a 3x3 grid where in each Square 9 numbers are generated also in a 3x3 grid.

Along with this i store the created DOM-Nodes in 3 Javascript classes: Grid, Square and Field. Square extends Grid and Field extends Square and Grid.

### Wanted Situation

In the end I want that Grid holds an Array of all Squares and an Array of all Fields. Squares and fields should inherit those Arrays then. I require this for a Sudoku generator.

At the moment each Square has all Squares and Each field has all Fields and all Squares. Grid only its own Element and only its own Class.

Is there any way to have a variable in Grid holding Squares and Fields, and everytime a new Field or Square gets constructed, Grid updates this variable?
Or is this nesting all wrong?

---

Grid.js

```
export class GridClass
{
    gridElem;

    constructor()
    {
        this.gridElem = this.getGridElem();
        console.log(this)
    }

    getGridElem = () => document.getElementById("grid");

}

export let GridInstance = new GridClass();
```

---

Square.js

```
import {GridClass} from "./Grid";

export class SquareClass extends GridClass
{
    squareElem;
    squares;
    squareID;

    constructor(squares, squareElem, squareID, gridElem)
    {
        super(gridElem);
        this.squareID = squareID;
        this.squares = squares;
        this.squareElem = this.getSquareElem();
    }

    getSquareElem = () => {
        return document.getElementsByClassName("square")[this.squares.length];
    }
}
```

---

Field.js

```
import {SquareClass} from "./Square";

export class FieldClass extends SquareClass
{
    fieldElem;
    fields;
    squareElem;

    constructor(gridElem, fieldElem, fields, squares, squareID)
    {
        super(gridElem, squares, squareID);
        console.log(squareID)
        this.fieldElem = fieldElem;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.squareElem = document.getElementsByClassName("square")[this.squares.length-1];
    }
}
```

---

Renderer.js

```
import {SquareClass} from "../dom/Square.js";
import {FieldClass} from "../dom/Field.js";

class RendererClass 
{
    squares;
    fields;

    constructor()
    {
        this.squares = new Array();
        this.fields = new Array();
    }

    renderGrid = () => {
        let squareJSON = {
            nodeName: "div",
            classes: ["square", "grid"],
        }
        let fieldJSON = {
            nodeName: "div",
            textNode: "0",
            classes: ["field"],
        }

        for(let squareCount=0; squareCount<9; squareCount++){
            let squareElement = this.createElement(document.getElementById("grid"), squareJSON);
            this.getSquarePosition(squareCount);
            this.squares.push(new SquareClass(this.squares, squareElement, squareCount));

            for(let fieldCount=0; fieldCount<9; fieldCount++) {
                let fieldElement = this.createElement(document.getElementsByClassName("square")[squareCount], fieldJSON);
                this.fields.push(new FieldClass(this.squares, fieldElement, this.fields))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using subclasses for this. Subclasses are for IS-A relationships, not HAS-A relationships.

Comment: What is `super(gridElem)` supposed to mean? The `Grid` constructor doesn't take a parameter.

Comment: well yes this is messy, give me a minute

Comment: But basically, you're going about this totally wrong.

Comment: Basicially i want to reference all existing squares and fields to all squares and fields. and to connect each Square and Field class to its DOM-Node.
Im giving it another try and avoid subclasses. thanks @Barmar

Comment: If something is a "part" of something else, it's not a subclass. A wheel is not a subclass of a car, a car contains an array of wheels.

Comment: feels uglier but works better..